# missing operand at _@_ in tcl script

Tags: shell, if-statement, open-source, tcl, tclsh

in if condition I want to check whether the string contains the pattern, but i'm getting following error.
`missing operand at _@_
in expression " $extra_url eq _@_*user-new* "
    (parsing expression " $extra_url eq *user-n...")
    invoked from within
"if { $extra_url eq *user-new* } {`

code is as follows :

```
if { $extra_url eq *user-new* } {
     ds_add rp [list notice "File $root/$extra_url: Not found" $startclicks [clock clicks -milliseconds]]
     ds_add rp [list transformation [list notfound "$root / $extra_url" $val] $startclicks [clock clicks -milliseconds]]

 }
```

here I'm checking whether the extra_url string contains "user_new".
I don't know whether I'm doing it right. please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is on this line:

```
if { $extra_url eq *user-new* } {
```

The issue is that the expression parser treats the first `*` of `*user-new*` as a multiply operator, and you've got two binary operators in a row without a value-token in between, which is illegal syntax. Indeed, to the expression parser, you might as well have written:

```
$extra_url eq * user - new *
```

OK, that's only after tokenizing, and has other problems after the double operator, namely unrecognised barewords and a trailing binary operator; the parse *will* fail. (Yes, the expression parser is a pretty traditional parser, not entirely different (albeit simpler than) those used to parse C or Java or …)

I'm guessing you *actually* want either string equality with a literal token (put the token in `{`braces`}` or `"`double-quotes`"`) or you want to use a command to test for some more complex case, such as a glob match with `string match`. Thus, pick one of these:

```
if { $extra_url eq {*user-new*} } {
```

```
if { $extra_url eq "*user-new*" } {
```

```
if { [string match *user-new* $extra_url] } {
```

Answer (score 1):

checking whether the extra_url string contains "user_new":

```
if {[string match {*user_new*} $extra_url]} { ... }

if {[string first "user_name" $extra_url] != -1} { ... }

switch -glob $extra_url {
    {*user_name*} { ... }
}

if {[regexp "user_name" $extra_url]} { ... }
```

`eq` is used strictly for string equality.

Comment: I wrote something like this 
`if {[string match {*user_new*} $extra_url]}
        {
   set extra_url "filenotfound"
               }`
it gave error as `wrong # args: no script following "[string match {*user_new*} $extra_url]" argument
    while executing
"if {[string match {*user_new*} $extra_url]}"`.

Comment: Did you put the opening brace on a new line? Tcl does not allow that. The `if` command requires at least 2 arguments and (since newline is a command terminator) you only gave it 1.

Comment: Did the changes, but now facing following error
`extra characters after close-brace
    while executing
"if {[string match {*user_new*} $extra_url]}{
   set extra_url "filenotfound"
   continue
         } ad_try {
            rp_serve_abstract_file "$root..." `

Comment: Tcl is like the shell in that the basic syntax is `command arg arg ...` -- the individual arguments are separated by spaces. If you smash 2 arguments together without whitespace, then Tcl complains. The complete rules for Tcl syntax can be found [here](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/Tcl.htm) (only 12 rules). You might also benefit from running through the [Tcl tutorial](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/tcltutorial.html).

Comment: Thanks for the help. but would you be able to tell me what was wrong with this code or what is the right version of this code?

Comment: You need a space between `}{`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are trying an exact string comparison, complementing on Donal Fellows', from the manual pages (with cuts and adaptations):

The [if command](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/if.htm) evaluates the condition as an expression (in the same way that expr evaluates its argument).

[Operands for the expr command](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/expr.htm#M5) may be specified in any of the following ways:

4. As a string enclosed in double-quotes. [...]
5. As a string enclosed in braces. [...]

---

Note that it implicitly excludes bare strings. They must be enclosed.

I am not sure why (maybe precisely to avoid confusion between a * as in a string like yours and valid expr operators) and thus it bites me once in a while too.